# SQL to get distinct statistics

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have data in table X:

```
id     assign  team
 ----------------------  
 1     hunkim    A  
 1     ygg       A  
 2     hun       B  
 2     gw        B  
 2     david     B  
 3     haha      A
```

I want to know how many assigns for each id. I can get using:

> select id, count(distinct assign) from
>   X  group by id 
>   order by count(distinct assign)desc;

It will give me something:

```
1  2
2  3
3  1
```

My question is how can I get the average of the all assign counts?

In addition, now I want to know the everage per team. So I want to get something like:

```
team    assign_avg
-------------------
A         1.5
B         3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain why A should be 1.5 and B 3? I can't really see what calculation you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    AVG(CAST(assign_count AS DECIMAL(10, 4)))
FROM
    (SELECT
        id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT assign) AS assign_count
    FROM
        X
    GROUP BY
        id) Assign_Counts
```

.

```
SELECT
    team,
    AVG(CAST(assign_count AS DECIMAL(10, 4)))
FROM
    (SELECT
        id,
        team,
        COUNT(DISTINCT assign) AS assign_count
    FROM
        X
    GROUP BY
        id,
        team) Assign_Counts
GROUP BY
    Team
```

Comment: This works well. How can I get the AVG in float? It gives me just int values.

Comment: You just need to CAST the count column (you can either do it in the subquery or as I did in the outer query above).

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be done in one query, using aggregate functions COUNT and AVG:

```
  SELECT t.id,
         COUNT(*) AS num_instances,
         AVG(t.id) AS assign_avg
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.id
```

Columns that do not have an aggregate function performed on them need to be defined in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You can't do AVG on (*). You need to have a numeric expression in there.